# SharePoint Search service error

Tags: 2010, search, provisioning

I am trying to to install search service on SharePoint 2010 farm, and getting following error

> Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service
>   Application.

In logs I found following error:

```
The call to SearchServiceInstance.Provision (server '<servername>') failed. Setting back to previous status 'Disabled'. System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UnsafeNativeMethods.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(String groupName)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UnsafeNativeMethods.TraceLocalGroups()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Provision()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminUtils.DeployLocalServiceInstance[T](T localSearchServiceInstance)
```

I have checked WSS_WPG group it does not have many users, as suggested by some soultions. Any help, clues to where to look for this error

Comment: have you ever resolved this?
Thanks
Tobias

Comment: @Tobias - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jijoseph/2018/01/31/arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-exception-while-modifying-search-topology/

Comment: @Tobias Review the uls logs to find the appropriate group name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking into ULS Logs deeper to find the group name? It does not necessarily have to WSS_WPG Group.

> From this we could figure out that it errors out while enumerating members of one of the local group. On a closer review of the ULS logs I was able to figure out the problematic group:

Reference : [Technet blog about issue](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jijoseph/2018/01/31/arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-exception-while-modifying-search-topology/)